# com.android.dex.DexException given when trying to integrate Youtube Data API into android app

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api, android-multidex

When I try to integrate Youtube DATA Api functionality into my app, I finally managed to resolve all errors. But when I run the project, it gives me the following error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/api/client/auth/oauth/AbstractOAuthGetToken;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```

My build.gradle file is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "wheresapp.iiitb.com.wheresapp"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),   'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev152-1.21.0'
compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/api-1.3.jar')
compile files('libs/json-simple.jar')
compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.16.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-jetty-1.11.0-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-java6-1.11.0-beta.jar')
}
```

I have looked at so many examples here but I am unable to resolve this error. If I set

```
multidexenabled true
```

In the Gradle file this error vanishes but I get another error

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/api/client/auth/oauth/package-info.class
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
```

Do you really need in your app all Google Play Services API? 
You can just integrate what you actually need. Follow the instruction [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) - Section "Selectively compiling APIs into your executable"

Comment: I am using that to use google maps.. any idea what I should change it to?

Comment: Remove that line and put com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0

Comment: I did.. it says failed to find it

Comment: same error... do you think its because of weak internet connection?

Comment: Gradle download all libraries you don't have in the repo. So, you need the library first downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev152-1.21.0'
compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-4.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/api-1.3.jar')
compile files('libs/json-simple.jar')
compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.16.0-rc.jar')
compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-jetty-1.11.0-beta.jar')
compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-java6-1.11.0-beta.jar')
}
```

It should work in this way and you won't need the

```
multidexenabled true
```

anymore.

Comment: I am still getting Error:Failed to find: com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0
Open FileOpen in Project Structure dialog

Comment: I dont think its because of this... I tried using 8.1 instead of 8.3 and my original errors were still there

Comment: are you able to share your project?

Comment: I was able to solve this in an alternate way that doesn't require any jar downloads at all. So no jar duplications at all. I have described this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982758/making-use-of-youtube-data-api-to-retrieve-video-details-in-android-app-based-on/33982759#33982759).