# Making use of Youtube DATA API to retrieve video details in android app based on keyword

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-data-api

I have extensively tried to Making use of Youtube DATA API to retrieve youtube video details in android app based on keyword, by downloading the example [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/java).

It leads to lot of import complexities,conflicts and duplicate dexing as described in my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33975264/com-android-dex-dexexception-given-when-trying-to-integrate-youtube-data-api-int/33975672?noredirect=1#comment55711875_33975672).

Is there a simpler way to do this using Java for an android app?

Comment: Fix here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969507/how-to-retrieve-details-of-single-video-from-youtube-using-videoid-through-data/39478514#39478514

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is!!

You can just make a simple GET HTTP request to youtube based on the examples they have listed in the documenation [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/). This **does not require any google api JAR downloads**.

Code example :

```
MakeHTTPRequest makeHTTPRequest = new MakeHTTPRequest();
    String response = "";
    String apiKey = MY_KEY; //Set your Android Key here

    String query = "";
    // input = input.replace(",","+");
    if(input.contains(" "))
        query = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=%22"+input.replace(" ","+")+"%22&type=video&key="+apiKey;
    else
        query = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=%22="+input+"%22&type=video&key="+apiKey;
    try {
        response = makeHTTPRequest.sendGet(query);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Youtube results : "+response);

    JSONObject responseJSON= null;
    try {
        responseJSON = new JSONObject(response);

        JSONArray items = responseJSON.getJSONArray("items");


        for(int i=0;i<items.length();i++){
            System.out.println("Item "+i+" : ");
            System.out.println("Title : "+items.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("snippet").get("title"));
            System.out.println("Description : "+items.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("snippet").get("description"));
            System.out.println("URL : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v="+items.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("id").getString("videoId"));



        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Additional things needed:**

1. Get your [API_KEY](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application).
2. You will need to download the **org.json** jar or any other supporting jar for JSON parsing the output.
3. You also need to include the code here on [How to send HTTP request GET/POST in Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/).

**EDIT 1**: Remove videoCaption parameter to get matching results with Youtube website.

**EDIT 2**: If you want to search for say a phrase *spice boat* then input should be enclosed in quotes, that is, variable

```
input = "%22spice+boat%22";
```

Then the search is truely accurate.